# How can I plot slice of certain DataFrame for each row with different color?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, indexing

I would like to plot certain slices of my `Pandas Dataframe` for each rows (based on row indexes) with **different colors**.

My data look like the following:
[image: img]

I already tried with the help of this [tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-concatenation-tutorial/) to find a way but I couldn't - probably due to a lack of skills.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("D:\SOF10.csv" , header=None)
df.head()

#Slice interested data
C = df.iloc[:, 2::3]

#Plot Temp base on row index colorfully
C.apply(lambda x: plt.scatter(x.index, x, c='g'))
plt.show()
```

Following is my expected plot:
[image: img]

I was also wondering if I could displace the mean of each row of the sliced data which contains 480 values somewhere in the plot or in the legend beside of plot! Is it feasible (like the following picture) to calculate the mean and displaced somewhere in the legend or by using small font size displace next to its own data in graph ?

**Data sample:** [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u3Jgeaq49DZXCSbPiQQQ4epIPyTIknVJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try remove ` c='g'` in `C.apply(lambda x: plt.scatter(x.index, x, c='g'))`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Hi , I did already and I updated the picture but as it can be seen it's not what I want to.

Comment: That's because you didn't slice/handle the data correctly, not because of how you would plot it.`C = df.iloc[:, 2::3]`still keeps the index for the sliced columns. So all the series plotted shares the same indices. That's why you see all the dots interleaved, not separated.

Comment: @QuangHoang oh I see so what's your suggestion ? How can I fix it? Is there any remedy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the plot without legend

```
C = df.iloc[:,2::3].stack().reset_index()
C.columns = ['level_0', 'level_1', 'Temperature']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
C.plot('level_0', 'Temperature', 
       ax=ax, kind='scatter', 
       c='level_0', colormap='tab20', 
       colorbar=False, legend=True)
ax.set_xlabel('Cycles')
plt.show()
```

Edit to reflect modified question:

1. `stack()` transform your (sliced) dataframe to a series with index (row, col)
2. `reset_index()` reset the double-level index above to `level_0` (row), `level_1` (col).
3. `set_xlabel` sets the label of x-axis to what you want.

Edit 2: The following produces scatter with legend:

```
CC = df.iloc[:,2::3]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(16,9))
labels = CC.mean(axis=1)

for i in CC.index:
    ax.scatter([i]*len(CC.columns[1:]), CC.iloc[i,1:], label=labels[i])

ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel('Cycles')
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The output didn't fulfill my expected result while I wanted to plot each row by different color! May i ask you check it out again the output picture?

Comment: Are you sure each row a color or each column a color?

Comment: surely each row sir !

Comment: I also provided the data sample in the post you can plot it. The outcome of your answer was far from my expectation in spite of being colorful and x-axis wasn't base on **row-indexes** from 0 to 40

Comment: I just updated the expected result picture hope it transfers my mindset better !

Comment: I'm kinda lost as to what you want. You can try drop `.T` before `stack()` and try replace `'idx'` inside `plot` by `'level_0'`. I can't access google drive for now.

Comment: man it worked perfectly ! if you had an idea to improve colors plz and edit your answer since it's a bit difficult to differentiate between the colors due to they are so similar. I mean It would be nice if composition of colors are much distinguishable and different. I'm also curious about what are `idx`, `level_0`,`level_1`,`val` shortly. if you leave some comments in your answer, it would be great. I will accept it as the answer of this question surely

Comment: Is there any way to displace average of each row with its own color beside of plot ?

Comment: another issue when i get plot description under x-axis is "level_0" while I need to edit to my desired description which is "Cycles" ! and Y axis should be "Temperature" instead of val. I hope when you access google drive and plot you understand me better.

Comment: Thanks for update it was what I want but do u know how I could change the color to `mapcolor='prism`? I also could improve the legend position by `ax = plt.gca()
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.1), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)` and it looks nice! I also have another similar question regarding this issue to levelize the plot I would like to ask separately [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55270346/how-can-fit-the-data-on-temperature-thermal-profile?) with this(current) post dataset and dataframe and data slice. i would appreciate that if you have a look on that.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an approximate answer. `scatter(c=, cmap=` can be used for desired coloring.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[34,22,1,34]})
fig, subplot_axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20, 10))  # width, height

colors = ['red','green','blue','purple']
cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)

for col in df.columns:
    subplot_axes.scatter(df.index, df[col].values, c=df.index, cmap=cmap, alpha=.9)
```

Comment: This is coloring columnwise.  The question wants the markers to be colored based on their ordinal position in the column (index).

Comment: Hi Thanks for response question is about either accessing desired data or plotting them based on row index **row-wise**

Comment: Updated to use colors from df.index.  @Quan Hoang provides a more succinct answer.

Comment: the output of your answer is totally different from my expected result since it displays colorful columns!

Comment: I just updated the expected result picture hope it transfers my mindset better !